# Need to parse image src from HTML page then display it

Tags: java, android, html, image, parsing

I'm currently trying to develop an app whereby it visits the following site (Http://lulpix.com) and parses the HTML and gets the img src from the following section

```
<div class="pic rounded-8" style="overflow:hidden;"><div style="margin:0 0 36px 0;overflow:hidden;border:none;height:474px;"><img src="**http://lulpix.com/images/2012/April/13/4f883cdde3591.jpg**" alt="All clogged up" title="All clogged up" width="319"/></div></div>
```

Its of course different every time the page is loaded so I cannot give a direct URL to an Asynchronous gallery of images which is what i intend to do, for instance

**Load Page > Parse img src > download ASync to imageview > Reload lulpix.com > start again**

Then place each of these in an image view from which the user can swipe left and right to browse.

So the TL;DR of this is, how can i parse the html to retrieve the URL and has anyone got any experiences with libarys for displaying images.

Thank you v much.

Comment: Consider using JSoup, it's a pretty reliable way to parse HTML found in "the wild".

Comment: I was looking a JSoup though i cant seem to find a method of parsing i can use

Comment: Alrighty. I'll whip one up, it's super-easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an AsyncTask that connects to lulpix, fakes a referrer & user-agent (lulpix tries to block scraping with some pretty lame checks apparently). Starts like this in your `Activity`:

```
new ForTheLulz().execute();
```

The resulting `Bitmap` is downloaded in a pretty lame way (no caching or checks if the image is already DL:ed) & error handling is overall pretty non-existent - but the basic concept should be ok.

```
class ForTheLulz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... args) {
            Bitmap result = null;
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://lulpix.com")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .get();
                        //parse("http://lulpix.com");
                if (doc != null) {
                    Elements elems = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "pic rounded-8");
                    if (elems != null && !elems.isEmpty()) {
                        Element elem = elems.first();
                        elems = elem.getElementsByTag("img");
                        if (elems != null && !elems.isEmpty()) {
                            elem = elems.first();
                            String src = elem.attr("src");
                            if (src != null) {
                                    URL url = new URL(src);
                                    // Just assuming that "src" isn't a relative URL is probably stupid.
                                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                                    try {
                                        result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                    } finally {
                                        is.close();
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Error handling goes here
            }
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            ImageView lulz = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lulpix);
            if (result != null) {
                lulz.setImageBitmap(result);
            } else {
                //Your fallback drawable resource goes here
                //lulz.setImageResource(R.drawable.nolulzwherehad);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very helpful indeed! however we're you able to test it successfully? i seem to get a null result each time hmm

Comment: yup. try printing the resulting Document, the toString() will show you what you're receiving from the server.

Comment: I feel very stupid! aha, i made such a silly mistake, excuse me while i huddle in the corner and cry. working beautifully thank yo very much!

Comment: @BhavikAmbani : [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a HTML processing library, i.e. it will happily eat the ugly, malformed garbage that web "developers" around the world churn out. Useful for scraping web pages for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used JSoup to parse invalid HTML, it works well! Do something like...

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
    Element img = doc.body().select("div[class=pic rounded-8] img").first();
    String src = img.attr("src");
```

Play with the "selector string" to get it right, but I think the above will work. It first selects the outer `div` based on the value of its `class` attribute, and then any descendent `img` element.

Comment: This is exactly what i had tried, however i get a persistent NullPointerExeception *sigh* haha

Comment: The expression must not be right I guess... Try getting just the div first; "div[class=pic rounded-8]"

Answer (score 0):

No need to use webview now check this sample project

**https://github.com/meetmehdi/HTMLImageParser.git**

In this sample project I am parsing html and image tag, than extracting the image from image URL. Image is downloaded and is displayed.