# How can I parse html image in webview to display imageview?

Tags: android, parsing, webview, imageview, captcha

I want to get html image in the webview and display to imageview.

I do not want a solution as well as the URL of the picture downloads.

I have tried the following.

```
public class WebViewClientFix extends WebViewClient
{
    private Bitmap bmpCaptcha;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,SslError error) 
    {
        handler.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

        public Bitmap getBmpCaptcha() 
        {
        return bmpCaptcha;
    }

    public void setBmpCaptcha(Bitmap bmpCaptcha) 
    {
        this.bmpCaptcha = bmpCaptcha;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    imageView =   (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webClinent = new WebViewClientFix();
    webClinent.setContext(this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(webClinent);
    webview.loadUrl("https://xxxxx.tr/login");      
}
```

How should I follow a solution?

thanks

Comment: What is an "html image"? You're loading some resource via http, presumably some html page ; what image are you talking about?

Comment: <img src="captcha.jpg"/> like

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the WebView.

Comment: I connecting https://esgm.sgk.gov.tr/Esgm/LoginT.action the url with webview.

I want to handle captcha image and display imageview.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644885/2695282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample
https://github.com/ismailkocacan/Android-Captcha-Handler/blob/master/test/src/com/test/captchahandler/MainActivity.java

- I draw same captcha image using html5 canvas in webview. (Javascript side)

  - Later convert to canvas image to base64 image string (Javascript side)
  - Send base64 image string to android side and convert to byte image.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the page, parse its content (jsoup might help), identify the image(s) you want, and fetch them.

Comment: the captcha image url https://esgm.sgk.gov.tr/Esgm/Captcha.jpg
But the picture is changing requests.
So.I must handle downloaded current captcha image. :)

Comment: Have you find a solution? I have a captcha that changes on every request. So if, I get the image url is not enough because, on the second request the image is changing. Somehow I would have to extract the downloaded bitmap but I don't know how...

Comment: @İsmailKocacan i have the same problem, please any solution for that ? i tried using javascript to get a screenshot but didn't succeed

Comment: @Coder i have the same problem, please any solution for that ? i tried using javascript to get a screenshot but didn't succeed

Comment: @Coder you can look at here https://github.com/ismailkocacan/Android-Captcha-Handler/blob/master/test/src/com/test/captchahandler/MainActivity.java

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve it. You have to convert the image in base64 string and after you will have to regenerate it on "server" side

Comment: My solve don't regenerate image, you can try my samples and I draw "same" image using html5 canvas at client side.